# Rename spacy's pos tagger labels

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

i'm looking for something specific and didn't really found an answer: I'm looking to rename the pos tags label of spacy.
E.g. if i have this code:

```
def eng(textstr):    
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
    doc = nlp(textstr)
    for token in doc:
    print("Word: "+token.text+ " "+"POS: "+token.pos_)
```

I want token.pos_ to give me NIA instead of NOUN, BO instead of VERB, etc... I don't want to retrain anything if i can. The results given by the pos tagger are accurate enough for me, i just want to rename each label (Noun to NIA, Verb to BO, etcc..). So instead of having a NOUN i want token.pos_ to give me back NIA. First is this possible and if it is, how can i do it?
The first thing that came me to mind is to use simply an if statement:

```
if token.pos_ == "NOUN"
  print("Word: "+token.text+ " "+"POS: NIA")
```

but that cannot be done because than i have to change about 5000 functions, which is impossible. Is there another way? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. The `.pos` attribute specifically only holds Universal Dependency tags, and will give an error if you try to set another value. You can set any value in the `.tag` attribute if you want, though it's designed for language specific fine-grained tags, which have more detail than UD tags.

I am not really sure why you would want to do this instead of just getting used to the real tags, and I suspect that trying to change this will cause you a lot of headaches for little benefit, like redefining keywords in a programming language.

That said, the easiest way to do this is probably to define a [custom token extension](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components-attributes), call it `my_pos`, that translates the real tags to your tags. That would look a little like this:

```
POS_MAP = {"NOUN": "NIA", "VERB": "BO", ...}

def my_pos_getter(token):
    return POS_MAP[token.pos_]

Token.set_extension("my_pos", getter=my_pos_getter)

doc = nlp("I have a pen")
assert doc[3]._.my_pos == "NIA"
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution polm23!